# How to set up X-POWERED-BY in weblogic.xml?

Tags: http-headers, weblogic

Here stated that it is possible to set X-POWERED-BY header appearance. But I don't see any way how to define this property through `weblogic.xml`. Anyone know how to do this?

> In general, these properties can be overridden at the cluster level
>   (in ClusterMBean, if the same property is present there), the server
>   level (in ServerMBean, if the same property is present there) or for a
>   specific Web application (in weblogic.xml)

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/wlsmbeanref/core/index.html

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you should try is editing your domain setting through the admin console:

```
<domain name> -> Configuration -> Web Applications
```

Change the `X-Powered-By Header:` drop down to [whatever setting you need](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/ConsoleHelp/pagehelp/Corecoredomaindomainconfigwebapptitle.html).

---

For a specific application, like a servlet, you can also call this method:

```
HttpServletResponse setHeader()
```

---

If you need to remove it via your web.xml file, you can try:

```
 <context-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.faces.sendPoweredByHeader</param-name>
   <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

---

If you want to set it using WLST try:

```
connect(username, password, host_info)
edit()
cd("/WebAppContainer/" + domainName)
startEdit()

# set to NONE, SHORT, MEDIUM, or FULL
cmo.setXPoweredByHeaderLevel("NONE")

activate()
```

Comment: thanks, I know about these ways. But I need something in weblogic.xml or confirmation that this is not possible in weblogic.xml

Comment: I believe you can only set it with the above methods - it is a domain-wide setting, not app specific, unless you edit servlet responses.